# Add, Update, Delete from a ndb.KeyProperty() - Google Cloud Datastore NDB

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Here are my *many-to-many relationship* models:

```
class ModelA(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=true)
    model_b = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=ModelB,repeated=True)


class ModelB(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=true)
    model_a = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=ModelA,repeated=True)
```

My question is, how do I add/update/delete a single (or many) KeyProperty from let's say **model_b**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it like this:

```
pos = ModelA.model_b.index(ndb.Key('ModelB',213)) # Get position from list
ModelA.model_b.pop(pos) # Remove from list
ModelA.put() # Update
```