# Why ValueError when deleting a KeyProperty type to one-to-many relationship. How to fix it?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, webapp2

I have a one-to-many relationship NDB entity model b/w post and comment models. I am trying to remove the comment from the comments list after deleting the comment entity from db. Below is my code for deleting comment:

```
idx = post.comments.index(ndb.Key('Comment',comment_id))
post.comments.pop(pos) # Remove comment from comments list
```

I am getting the error such as:

> ValueError: Key('Comment', '6614661952700416') is not in list

But on Datastore Viewer I can see the comment there:

```
[datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'Comment', 6614661952700416L, _app=u'dev~testData2')]
```

Post Model:

```
class Post(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    body = ndb.TextProperty(required=True)
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)

    author_id = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)

    comments = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Comment, repeated=True)
```

Here on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819992/add-update-delete-from-a-ndb-keyproperty-google-cloud-datastore-ndb) it seems to be working.

Comment: Try converting the ID to an int `idx = post.comments.index(ndb.Key('Comment', int(comment_id)))`. The error message suggests it's interpreted as a string. Also the optional `_app` being displayed in the viewer is rather unusual. How was the comment created? Is `'dev~testData2'` matching your app?

Comment: that fixed the problem. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the comment to an answer.

The error message suggests that `comment_id` is interpreted as a string, not as a long/int (emphasis mine):

> ValueError: Key('Comment', **'6614661952700416'**) is not in list

While the datastore entry corresponds to a long key ID:

> [datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'Comment', **6614661952700416L**, _app=u'dev~testData2')]

So just explicitly cast `comment_id` to a number:

```
idx = post.comments.index(ndb.Key('Comment', int(comment_id)))
```